# A good GPU based de-noiser for AMD?

Tags: gpu, osx, denoise

Is there any decent de-noiser for AMD GPU's on macOS via Metal? I've been using my new AMD eGPU for Cycles X since support was released a few weeks ago, but one of the problems were that the openimagedenoiser is really slow (my CPU) is slow.

So, Is there a decent,quick GPU Based de-noiser for AMD GPU's on macOS for at least viewport rendering? (I can use openimagedenoise for final renders)

Answer (score 1):

There is none that I'm aware of, yet.
Intel has demo'd OpenImageDenoise running on GPU (not public atm) so maybe soon.

Comment: Is this a beta? Is there a way I can download this?

Comment: @SkylineX I'm not aware of this being available to the public yet. Just screenshots. I really want this too